# google analytics ga4, users possibly being double counted?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, next.js, google-analytics-4

I'm guessing the `Referral` metric in Google Analytics increments when the url has a `ref` in it (coming from a different site such as https://website.com?ref=facebook), but if the user clicks on a separate page and the `ref` param is dropped from the url, does that increment the `Direct` metric?

Just want to make sure users aren't being double counted since just yesterday the `Referral` and `Direct` metric were the same which was odd. If that is the case, is there a way to make sure they are not double counted?

[image: google analytics]

Using ga4

gtag.js

```
export const GA_TRACKING_ID = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GA_ID;

export const pageview = (url) => {
  window.gtag("config", GA_TRACKING_ID, {
    page_path: url,
  });
};

export const event = ({ action, category, label, value }) => {
  window.gtag("event", action, {
    event_category: category,
    event_label: label,
    value,
  });
};
```

_app.tsx in NextJS app

```
  const router = useRouter();
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleRouteChange = () => {
      gtag.pageview(window.location.href);
    };
    router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", handleRouteChange);
    router.events.on("hashChangeComplete", handleRouteChange);
    return () => {
      router.events.off("routeChangeComplete", handleRouteChange);
      router.events.off("hashChangeComplete", handleRouteChange);
    };
  }, [router.events]);
```

Comment: Based on the screenshot, you seem to be using Google Analytics 4. If you have enhanced turned on (the default), it tracks SPA style routing on the client, which may cause double counting (due to having both the default counting and your custom counting).

Comment: yes GA4, even when enhanced turned on, why would it count it as a new user? here i'm sending an event or pageview, but I'm not sure what specifically would make it count as a user for referral versus direct, it's a NextJS app with 2 separate pages